# Fill Pandas column with a fix value from a specific index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with following columns.

```
  id                                               label               parent
0 ID                                               LABEL               SC% split
1 https://lists/100000000006/terms                 MedDRA RMS List
2 https://lists/100000000006/terms/2937736         Nausea
3 https://lists/100000000006/terms/2937735         Fever
```

I would like to fill column 'parent' with value 'MedDRA RMS List' from index 2 onwards. How can I achieve this. Till now, the solutions I have seen fill the value to the entire column. Any help is highly appreciated.

The expected output is:

```
  id                                               label               parent
0 ID                                               LABEL               SC% split
1 https://lists/100000000006/terms                 MedDRA RMS List
2 https://lists/100000000006/terms/2937736         Nausea              MedDRA RMS List
3 https://lists/100000000006/terms/2937735         Fever               MedDRA RMS List
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df.loc[2:, 'parent'] = 'MedDRA RMS List'
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                         id            label           parent
0                                        ID            LABEL        SC% split
1          https://lists/100000000006/terms  MedDRA RMS List                 
2  https://lists/100000000006/terms/2937736           Nausea  MedDRA RMS List
3  https://lists/100000000006/terms/2937735            Fever  MedDRA RMS List
```